# Grey-out background when popup window is active - android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm looking for a way to grey out the background of my fragment when a popup window is active. When using an AlertDialog this is standard, but with a pop-up window I can seem to figure out how to do that...

The picture below shows what I would like to implement, but not with an AlertDialog, but with a popup window:

[AlertDialog example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Due7K.png)

Comment: I have done this before I will look for the code and paste it shortly.. if I am correct, you can change the fragment color by calling the fragment color on pop up activated, then when pop up is deactivated you change the fragment color back to the original color... I believe that's how I done it but I will post code if I can find it

Comment: That would be great! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found a solution myself. Let me know if there exists a more elegant solution. But it worked good enough for me:

I nested the popup window xml inside a Relativelayout with "match parent" properties for width and height and a "semi-transparent" background. As shown in the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#90000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="10dp"> 

        <!-- Your Popup xml-window -->

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the code, when creating a new popup window I set it to "MATCH_PARENT" in width and height:

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,true);
```

This results in the same appearance as an alert dialog, with two exceptions:

1. An alert dialog also darkens the status bar, and navigation buttons at the bottom of your phone. My solution is limited to the app its window.
2. When clicking outside an alert dialog box, the dialog is dismissed, In my case you have to implement a cancel button OR have the popup window dismissed when tapped.